# How to disallow a certain action?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I'd like to disallow `/questions/{ID}/foo` but not `/questions/{ID}`.

Is the syntax `Disallow: /questions/*/foo`?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start looking for the proper syntax should be [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html):

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are **not** supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot have lines like `"User-agent: *bot*"`, `"Disallow: /tmp/*"` or `"Disallow: *.gif"`.

Comment: I've added the most relevant paragraph that seems to answer the question as a quote.

Comment: That's according to the standard. It's not as black and white with Googlebot, which allows and understands Disallow: /*.gif$